# I cant prove this. i dont understand what will be my hypothesis for induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

Consider the sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2,\dots$ of integers defined by $a_0 = 10$ and $a_n = 2a_{n-1}$, $n \geq 1$. Prove that $a_n = 2^n\cdot10$ for all $n \geq 0$.

Comment: What did you try?  Do you understand how induction works?

Comment: Yes, but i am still learning. I know the basic step but I can go any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively:
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}=2(2a_{n-2})=2^2a_{n-2}=2^2(2a_{n-3})=2^3a_{n-3}=\cdots=2^na_0=2^n\cdot 10.$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all $n = 1$ : $a_{1} = 2\cdot10 = 2^{1} \cdot 10$.

Step : $a_{n-1} = 2^{n-1}\cdot10$, so $2a_{n-1} = 2\cdot2^{n-1}\cdot10=2^{n}\cdot10 = a_{n}$.

Comment: Thanks man. Its so simple.

Comment: Not sure I understand why this was downvoted.

Comment: @fleablood I'm too

Comment: @fleablood Only "fault" I can fathom is that the base case could have been taken to be $n=0\,$: $\;a_0=10 = 2^0 \cdot 10\,$, instead. Or, it could have been just a random drive-by downvote. Not worth worrying about in either case IMHO, annoying as it may be.

Comment: I'm not worrying and and generally don't care but every now and then I think I should let a person who did a decent answer but was down voted capriciously, know that it wasn't him; it was a weirdo downvoter.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the base case: $a_0=2^0\cdot10=10$

Assume: $a_n=2^n\cdot10$

What we want to prove: $a_{n+1}=2^{n+1}\cdot10$

Now,

$a_{n+1}=2a_n=2\cdot(2^n\cdot10)=(2\cdot2^n)\cdot10=2^{n+1}\cdot10$

Comment: Not sure that I see anything that openspace's answer didn't cover.